# XCode Interface builder missing view hierarchy

Tags: xcode, xcode6, interface-builder

I've just installed Xcode 6.4 on a new macbook and started a new project for some reason i can't find the view hierarchy usually present on the left hand side where i can see which views sit in which....

Hopefully this explains what I mean:

```
-view
---view
----label
----button
---view
----label
```

Comment: Apple calls that the "Document Outline".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It may be hide state. To show click icon where is shown in screenshot.

[image]

OR

as [@Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/307944/jeff) metioned in comments you can do it with `Editor->Show Document Outline`.
For more [info](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/Chapters/AboutInterfaceBuilder.html)

Comment: Thought id clicked every possible place!

Comment: Please add "Editor > Show Document Outline" to your answer. Maybe add a [link to docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/Chapters/AboutInterfaceBuilder.html) that Apple will surely cause to go stale in a few years.

Comment: True, devil is on details.